# How to find out when Gradle last cached the dependency

Tags: gradle

In my Gradle script, I declare JavaCC as a dependency in its own, custom "javacc" configuration. Then I use that configuration to find out the path to the JavaCC JAR and write that path to a property file which is later used by Ant, outside Gradle.

Right now, the relevant portions of my `build.gradle` file look like this:

```
configurations {
    javacc
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    javacc group: 'net.java.dev.javacc', name: 'javacc', version: '5.0'
}

task cleanBuildHelpers(type: Delete) {
    delete '.buildHelpers/ant.properties'
}

task prepareBuildHelpers(dependsOn: cleanBuildHelpers) << {
    ant.propertyfile(file: '.buildHelpers/ant.properties') {
        entry(key: 'javacc_jar', value: configurations.javacc.files.iterator().next())
    }
}
```

This works just like I want it to and I could leave it like that. However, the `prepareBuildHelpers` task is always executed, whenever I run some other task that depends on it. It's not a big deal, but I would like to know if there's a way to make it run only when Gradle updates the JavaCC JAR.

I was thinking along the lines of checking the timestamp of the JAR and comparing it to the timestamp of the property file, but I don't know whether this is the correct way and whether there's a better, more elegant way to do this.

Any ideas or advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct solution is to declare the inputs and outputs of the `prepareBuildHelpers` task. Assuming you want to rerun the task whenever the Jar file's path name (rather than its content) changes:

```
task prepareBuildHelpers(dependsOn: cleanBuildHelpers) {
    inputs.property "javaccJarPath", configurations.javacc.singleFile
    outputs.file '.buildHelpers/ant.properties'
    doLast {
        ant.propertyfile(file: '.buildHelpers/ant.properties') {
            entry(key: 'javacc_jar', value: configurations.javacc.singleFile
        }
    }
}
```

Since the task edits an existing file, the output declaration isn't quite accurate, and the task will be rerun after any external change to that file. If that's undesirable, try `outputs.upToDateWhen { true }` instead.

PS: Notice the simplified way of referring to the single file in a file collection.

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know about `.singleFile` nor that I could declare something like that as an input. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, I made `prepareBuildHelpers` depend on `cleanBuildHelpers`, precisely so that the property file gets deleted before generating it from scratch. Is it better to make `prepareBuildHelpers` a `Delete`-type task?

Comment: I didn't realize you were just generating a single-entry properties file. Your code will work but there are simpler solutions. I wouldn't turn `prepareBuildHelpers` into a `Delete` task because that's not its main purpose. If at all, I'd insert a `delete '.buildHelpers/ant.properties'` before `ant.propertyfile`. But probably I'd do the job in Groovy rather than in Ant. Something like `file('.buildHelpers/ant.properties').withOutputStream { stream -> def props = new Properties(); props['javacc_jar'] = configurations.javacc.singleFile.path; props.store(stream, null) }`.  No need to delete here.